# Вернуть результат из поля editText FragmentDialog в адаптер RecycleView

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter, dialogfragment

Я вызываю FragmentDialog в адаптере в поле editText этого FragmentDialog я меняю данные и отправляю на сервер данные по нажатию кнопки ОК диалога. Но проблема как вернуть эти данные которые я изменил в адаптер и вызвать NotifyDataSetChanged.

Кусок кода из адаптера:

```html
 
 .....
 holder.imagePref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //mValues.get(position).setCountUnread(0);
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext,view);
                    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_view_list_menu, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.show();
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()){
                                case R.id.send_arhive:
                                    SendToArhiveChat(position);

                                    break;
                                case R.id.rename_chat:
                                    startFragment(position);

                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            ..........
            
       private void startFragment(int position){
          FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(mContext);
          FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
          final RenameDialog f = new RenameDialog();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putString("id",String.valueOf(mValues.get(position).getChatID()));
          args.putString("name", mValues.get(position).getchatName());
          f.setArguments(args);
          f.show(fm,"num");
       
   }
```

Тут сам код класса DialogFragment:

```html
public class RenameDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {



    public String id;
    public String name;
    public Button cancel1, get1;
    public  EditText rename;
    public static RenameDialog f;

    public interface RenameDialogListener {

        void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText, String id);

    }

    static RenameDialog newInstance(String id, String name) {
        f = new RenameDialog();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("id", id);
        args.putString("name", name);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        id = getArguments().getString("id");
        name = getArguments().getString("name");

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rename_dialog, container, false);

       rename= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editName);
       if (name.equals("")) rename.setText("Клиент"+" "+id);
       else rename.setText(name);
        cancel1= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        get1= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.get_btn);
        cancel1.setOnClickListener(this);
        get1.setOnClickListener(this);

       return v;
    }






    private void sendName() {

        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().SendName(ManageAppPreferences.getToken(getContext()),id, rename.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("tag11111",response.body() );
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                // progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cancel_btn:
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.get_btn:
                sendName();
                dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);

    }

    // Call this method to send the data back to the parent fragment

    public void sendBackResult() {

        // Notice the use of `getTargetFragment` which will be set when the dialog is displayed

        RenameDialogListener listener = (RenameDialogListener) getTargetFragment();

        listener.onFinishEditDialog(rename.getText().toString(),id);

        dismiss();

    }

}
```

Функция sendBackResult() отправляет код в Fragment нашел данный пример на просторах инета. Как мне отправить данные в Адаптер и вызвать NotifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: можно снова послать запрос на сервер тем самым перезагрузить адаптер и заполнить новыми данными

Comment: Да это решение, мне это сразу же пришло в голову когда я понял, что  не знаю как вернуть результат из fragmentDialog, но это же колхоз))

Comment: В догонку вопрос в какое состояние переходит фрагмент, когда на передний план выходит fragmentDialog, чтоб корректно запросить данные на сервер?

Comment: Просто я сделал переопрос сервера в onStart фрагмента в котором recycleview всесто OnCreateView, а данные все равно не изменяются, надо перезапускать фрагмент.

Comment: Получается onFinishEditDialog вызывается во фрагменте и в этом же фрагменте должна храниться ссылка на адаптер. Его и дёргать. (DialogFragment не паузит фрагмент под ним)

Comment: да заимплементился от интерфейса, и вставил в функцию onFinishEditDialog Log.d("tag5151", inputText); но безрезультатно. Вот такую ошибку пишет Attempt to invoke interface method 'void .dialogs.RenameDialog$RenameDialogListener.onFinishEditDialog(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Comment: Чтобы getTargetFragment() возвращал родительский фрагмент нужно, что бы при создании DialogFragment он был задан через setTargetFragment(). Поищите простые примеры, например: https://habr.com/ru/post/259805/

Comment: Спасибо за статью, как раз то что нужно, что то гуглил она не попадалась, сейчас изучу.